# Bash getopts array empty

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm collecting `-t` and `-p` arguments in arrays, but they turn out empty. The strange thing is, that the same code works as intendet in another function.

```
declare -a TARGETS
declare -a PACKAGES
while getopts "t:p:" opt ; do
    case $opt in
        t) TARGETS+=("$OPTARG");;
        p) PACKAGES+=("$OPTARG");;
    esac
done
echo ${TARGETS[@]} # empty
echo ${PACKAGES[@]} # empty as well
```

The function is called like this:

```
func -t shared -t INFD_17 -p "barebox.afp=bootloader"  -p "barebox_env.afp=bootloader-env" -p kernel.afp -p rootfs.afp
```

EDIT: I needed to declare a few variables as local.

```
local OPTIND t p
declare -a TARGETS
declare -a PACKAGES
while getopts "t:p:" opt ; do
    case $opt in
        t) TARGETS+=("$OPTARG");;
        p) PACKAGES+=("$OPTARG");;
    esac
done
echo ${TARGETS[@]} # empty
echo ${PACKAGES[@]} # empty as well
```

Comment: I made an example [here](https://rextester.com/NSHI44834) by using your code, which is exacly the same. It is working

Comment: Well, it works the first time it's called, shure. The seceond time fails.

Comment: That helped, it works now.